# Can you do late havdalah after yom tov

Tags: yom-tov, havdalah

I know you can do havdala after shabbat till tuesday at sunset, with some restrictions, but can you do late havdalah after yom tov ended, also what if yom tov was on shabbat (for example yom kippur that was on shabbat)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Maharshal (to OC 299:6) rules that Havdala after Yom Tov has no late option and must be said that night. Rabbi Akiva Eiger (ibid.) quotes opinions who rule similarly, but he disagrees and rules that the following daytime is also included (ie. you have 24 hours from the end of Yom Tov). The Mishna Berura (ibid. sk 16) seems to rule this way, as does the Kitzur Shulchan Arukh ([196](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A7%D7%99%D7%A6%D7%95%D7%A8_%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9F_%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9A_%D7%A7%D7%A6%D7%95):15) and R Ovadia Yosef (Yabia Omer OC 7:47).

Birkei Yosef (OC 299) quotes an opinion that you have until the next Shabbat (or, seemingly, Yom Tov) to make up the Havdala.

Comment: This case is discussed a lot in the modern context of an Israeli visiting the Diaspora for a holiday, where Havdala after day one of the holiday isn't particularly convenient.

Comment: Why wouldn't it be convenient?  Just take a cup of wine and make havdala.

Comment: @heshy often enough in these cases you are a guest with a Diasporan for Yom Tov and you have to fit in with the local custom, so it's often inconvenient or impractical to get away from everyone and/or get wine in someone else's house.